# Trying to remove confidence bands and prediction bands from SAS REG procedure

Tags: sas, regression

My code

```
proc reg data=mydata plots=;
    title "Correlation Between Estriol Levels and Birthweights";
    model birthweight=estriol / clb cli clm;
run;
```

Plots the regression line and scatter plot but also includes the confidence bands and prediction bands. Is there a way I can hide one, the other, or both from the REG output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there's a way within PROC REG but you can accomplish something similar using PROC SGPLOT. See the documentation here for specifics such as modifying the colour/style or doing multiple lines. 
Here's an example that uses the SASHELP.CLASS data set as an example.

```
proc sgplot data=sashelp.class;
    reg x=age y=height;
run;
```

Documentation:
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/grstatproc/69716/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0mn6vl6clqbgyn1ivs69lezdxhf.htm

Answer (score 0):

By using `plots=;` you are requesting the default set of plots in the output. You probably want to suppress the default set using `plots(only)=` and then specifying only the graphics you want.

See the PROC REG statement options at http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/66859/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_reg_syntax01.htm